# Unable to run the flutter application

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

I get this error when I try running the application.

```
Error: unable to find directory entry in pubspec.yaml: /Users/yoshithKotla/Desktop/Freewheel_application/assets/images/
```

Comment: Show your pubspec.yaml and your project files tree

Answer (score 0):

```
 # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
     - assets/images/logo.png
```

comment out the assets: & make sure to get the path correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You should comment below part from `pubspec.yaml` if you haven't any directory `assets/images` in your project.

To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:

```
assets:
  - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
```

If you have assets and images folder than you should change your `pubspec.yaml` file like this,

To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:

```
assets:
  - assets/images
```